# ansible loop over a python list

Tags: python, ansible

I have an ansible role which contains the following tasks:

```
- name: get Units from xml - local action
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: true
  shell: python -c 'import parse_xml2json; print(parse_xml2json.parse("{{ env }}", "{{ component }}", "units", "unitID"))'
  args:
    chdir: "{{ scripts_path }}"
  register: units

- debug:
  var: "{{ units.stdout_lines }}"
```

It runs a python function named 'parse' from a file named 'parse_xml2json.py', and it's output looks like that:

```
"stdout_lines": [
        "['1', '3', '5', '7', '9', '11', '13', '15', '17', '19', '21', '23']"
```

But the debug task fails with an error:

```
"<type 'list'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!:"
```

I also have another task after these two, and it should take the output as a variable (as you can see above) and run a loop which runs the task on each one of the items.
How can I convert the python list variable ('units') to a list that ansible could read and loop over it?

Answer (score 0):

When using `var` with the `debug` module you do not enclose the variable with brackets. Doing so will cause the failure you are seeing.

The following should display as expected:

```
- debug:
    var: units.stdout_lines
```

Take a look at the examples in the documentation:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html#examples

Of course you may need to use brackets in other parts of your code.

Comment: The debug didn’t fail now but ansible still can’t read the units variable as a list and loop over it. It fails with the error:  “msg”: “Invalid data passed to ‘loop’, it requires a list, got this instead: units. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup.”  . I tried adding the wantlist=True but it failed with the error:  “reason”: “‘wantlist’ is not a valid attribute for a task...”